# Using webclients outputs access denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webclient

When i am using webclients in my project and when i run it says "access denied" and nothing else and it gets removed from my computer too
Here is the code

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
client.DownloadFile("example.com/a.txt", "a.txt");
}
```

Edit:
I dont think it with the code, i think it is getting flag when i am declaring the webclient it self`enter code here

```
var client = new WebClient()
```

That itself isnt working

```
enter code here

enter code here
```

Comment: How about giving it an absolute path `client.DownloadFile(new Uri("example.com/a.txt"), @"C:\Websites\a.txt");`

Comment: i have tried that too doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure user account running the application does have permission to write files to the folder C:\ drive in this example.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
    client.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://www.example.com/a.txt"), @"c:\a.txt"); 
}
```

Comment: is there a way to read a remote text file without webclients or http

Comment: @AgentMagma the error has nothing to do with WebClient or remote files. You're trying to write to a folder to which you have no permission to write. It could also be a read-only folder like `Program Files` or a folder that requires elevated privileges like the system root, `C:`. Use a different path

Comment: Yes there is but you are not solving your real problem here, which is as @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned you do not have the permission to write to the folder.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what do you mean i dont have wirte permissions like just declare webclient outputs that i think it could flag an anti-virus

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks same like below question on stack overflow.
Could you please try solution answered on below question?

Link: [Reading a remote text file line by line and comparing with inputbox entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813883/reading-a-remote-text-file-line-by-line-and-comparing-with-inputbox-entry)

Comment: yes execpt when i am declaring the webclient something removes the app maybe like an av